# Typescript error Type AnimatesDirective in is part of the declarations of 2 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

When I used below CLI, It shows the error. The error message is not clear to me.

```
> ionic cordova run android --prod --device
```

Error:

```
 typescript error
            Type AnimatesDirective in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.d.ts
            is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/src/app/app.module.ts and AnimatorModule in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.d.ts!
            Please consider moving AnimatesDirective in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.d.ts
            to a higher module that imports AppModule in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/src/app/app.module.ts and AnimatorModule in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.d.ts. You
            can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes AnimatesDirective in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animates.directive.d.ts
            then import that NgModule in AppModule in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/src/app/app.module.ts and AnimatorModule in
            D:/Freelance-Work/Clients/ionic3/node_modules/css-animator/angular/animator.module.d.ts.

Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at D:\Freelance-Work\Clients\ionic3\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (D:\Freelance-Work\Clients\ionic3\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (D:\Freelance-Work\Clients\ionic3\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (D:\Freelance-Work\Clients\ionic3\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
    at <anonymous>
```

Could you tell me how to sort out this issue?

*app.module.ts*

```
import { AnimationService, AnimatesDirective } from 'css-animator';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    AnimatesDirective
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppConfigModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
   ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    NativeStorage,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
    AnimationService,   
  ]
})
```

Comment: it seems you have 2 module in your app and declared AnimatesDirective in both.

Comment: How can I give a solution for this? @fatemefazli

Comment: Remove the declaration from app.module.ts, but update the AppModule configuration to import your another module.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Please put your comment as an answer. Then I can close this post. @fatemefazli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you have 2 module in your app and declared `AnimatesDirective` in both. Remove the declaration from `app.module.ts`, but update the `app.module.ts` configuration to import your another module.

*app.module.ts*

```
import { AnimatorModule } from 'css-animator';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    HttpClientModule,
    AppConfigModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AnimatorModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    NativeStorage,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
  ]
})
```